# Flutter CSV does only returns an instance of Future and not the value

Tags: android, flutter, csv, dart

I am building a language app and I have all of my class material stored in CSVs in the assets folder. I am trying to get flutter to load the data from the CSV cells into the app but flutter is only returning an instance of the future and not the value stored in the CSV

From the code below, in the `getData() async {}` method prints the correct value stored at `cell [1][1]` when flutter runs the line `print(await data[1][1]);` but the return line below that `return await data[1][1];` only returns `Instance of Future<dynamic>'` and not the value.

In summary, it is printing the csv value but not returning the csv value.

1. How can I get flutter to do what I want it to do?
2. Is async necessary for loading csv data from local storage?
3. Is there a better method of loading data into flutter using CSV? (I was building this exact app with kivy in python and this was very easy to accomplish but I had to switch to flutter)

```html
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class ClassContent extends StatelessWidget {
  ClassContent();

  List<List<dynamic>> data = [];
  loadAsset() async {
    final myData = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/class01.csv");
    List<List<dynamic>> csvTable = CsvToListConverter().convert(myData);
    data = csvTable;
  }

  getData() async {
    await loadAsset();
    print(await data[1][1]); // PRINTS THE CORRECT VALUE STORED IN THE CSV
    return await data[1][1]; // DOES NOT RETURN THE VALUE
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Phonica"), elevation: 0),
      body: ListView(children: [
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) ListTile(title: Text(getData().toString()))
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: but you're not telling getData() to return anything... you need to specify the type. If you don't specify, void is assumed.

Comment: How and where do I specify the type? I am coming from python so all of this is new to me.

Comment: Here is the full tour for Dart: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour but is just like any other OOP languages similar to C++, Java, etc it will be something like String getData() async or replace String with the class or type you're expecting to get

Answer (score 0):

The default return type in Dart is "void". Your async functions need to return a Future of a type. For example, because `data` is a `List<List<dynamic>>`, you're returning "dynamic" in getData():

```
Future<dynamic> getData() async {
    await loadAsset(); //should return Future<void>
    print(data[1][1]); //no await here because List lookup isn't async
    return data[1][1]; //no await here either
}
```